# Spring Boot + grpc logging + correlation id?

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I've got a Spring Boot app. Its a standard http rest api. I'm adding a grpc host inside of it to provide a parallel grpc experience. That part is all working fine. One of my requirements is request / response logging.

I've got a ServerInterceptor, a SimpleForwardingServerCall wrapper and a SimpleForwardingServerCallListener wrapper to trap all the places I need to log (success & failure calls).

I need to get the request body from onMessage and the status code from 2 places (one for fail, one for success) and then the elapsed time.

So long question short, I'm not sure how the threading model works in grpc, where can I store this information on a per request basis so by the time I get to onComplete() which has no params, I can access it?

I'm doing something like:

```
return new xxxServerCallListener<>(next.startCall(new xxxServerCall<>(call), headers), call);
```

So I assume a new xxxServerCallListener and xxxServerCall get created for each request and I can store stuff in there as it moves through the pipeline? Would that be the best place to store?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, construct your own `ServerCall.Listener` per-RPC and store the information there.

```java
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
      ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
      final Metadata headers,
      ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
    // resp could be stored in the call class, but then it would need to be
    // a named class which is more boilerplate. AtomicReference is
    // convenient.
    final AtomicReference<RespT> resp = new AtomicReference<>();
    call = new SimpleForwardingServerCall<ReqT, RespT>(call) {
      @Override public void sendMessage(RespT message) {
        // We assume we're getting immutable protobufs or something similar
        // that doesn't mutate. Otherwise we'd need to copy it here.
        resp.set(message);
        super.sendMessage(message);
      }
    };
    return new SimpleForwardingServerCallListener<ReqT>(next.startCall(call, headers)) {
      private ReqT req;

      @Override public void onMessage(ReqT message) {
        this.req = message;
        super.onMessage(message);
      }

      @Override public void onCancel() {
        // No point in using 'resp' as the client probably didn't use it.
        // Note that sendMessage() has likely not been called so 'resp' is
        // frequently null. If referencing 'resp' here, synchronizing (like
        // that provided by AtomicReference) is necessary.
        log(req);
        super.onCancel();
      }

      @Override public void onComplete() {
        // For properly-behaving callers (those that do not invoke
        // call.sendMessage() after call.close()), this actually doesn't
        // need to be synchronized as call.close() (and thus any
        // sendMessage()) is guaranteed to have been called by this point.
        log(req, resp.get());
        super.onComplete();
      }
    };
  }
```